# How to disable lock screen password but keep the lock screen?

Tags: ubuntu

I've tried googling it 100 ways but every solution involves disabling the lock screen entirely. I want to be able to have the screen lock, but instead of it prompting for a password I can just return to work with 'enter' or whatever.

Comment: You mean you want only the (blank) screensaver... Yes that's possible but without _any_ information on what desktop environment (beyond Ubuntu) it's not easy to say how.

Comment: Please click on `edit` above and to the left to edit your original post. Please specify the flavor and version number of Ubuntu you are using, and if you changed from the default Desktop Environment, which you changed to. Also, if you use a screen locker other than the default for that version and flavor, please also specify that as well.